# Updating values within array of dictionaries using Swift

Tags: json, macos, cocoa, swift

I am teaching myself Swift these days and have trouble understanding how to update values in dictionaries stored in an array. The array consists of dictionaries read from file using JSON (I am using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)). The JSON file looks like this:

```
 {
  "test2" : [
    {
      "files" : "203",
      "url" : "Optional(\"\/Users\/heisan\/test\/\")",
      "date" : "April 6, 2015 at 15:23:40 EDT"
    }
  ]
}
```

Each key:value pair in the dictionaries consists of String:Array where the Array again consists of String:String dictionaries. My function for updating the content for specific key looks like this:

```
 @objc func addOptionForKey(key: String, date: NSDate, url: NSURL, files: NSNumber)-> Bool {

        let dictData: NSData? = self.createDataOfDictionary()
        if (dictData != nil) {
            let json = JSON(data: dictData!)

            for (localkey: String, var subJson: JSON) in json {

                var backups: Array = [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]()

                var restores = subJson.arrayValue
                for restore in restores {
                    let innerDict: [String:String] = ["url":restore["url"].stringValue,
                        "files":restore["files"].stringValue,
                        "date":restore["date"].stringValue]

                    backups.append(innerDict)
                }
                self.restoreDict[localkey]=backups    
        } 
        return true
}
```

Here, a the restoreDict property is defined as

> self.restoreDict = String:[AnyObject]

The function crashes when I try to update my array for the specific key:

> self.restoreDict[localkey]=backups

I am sure I am doing some amateur error here but a kick in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. T

**Update:** My problem turned out to be related to my version of Xcode and Swift. When I switched to Xcode 6.3 + Swift 1.2 as well as moving away from using swiftJSON (as Swift 1.2 has many improvements for handling JSON) everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
var restoreDict = [String:[String:AnyObject]]()

let test2 = ["files" : 203, "url" : "blah", "date" : "April 6, 2015 at 15:23:40 EDT"]

restoreDict["local"] = test2

println(restoreDict)

// prints "[local: [files: 203, url: blah, date: April 6, 2015 at 15:23:40 EDT]]"
```